# При открытии файла через FileStream, выдает исключение InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, исключения, uwp, filestream

Пишу UWP-приложение. 
Есть метод:

```
static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(string imageFilePath)
{
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
        return binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
}
```

При его вызове из другого метода выпадает исключение InvalidOperationException:

> Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread. Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.

Ругается именно на эту строчку:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Что делать, господа? Где-то видел решение с помощью Task.Run, но увы, не помогло.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте переписать метод чтения файла на [чтение в асинхронном режиме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081740/uwp-async-read-file-into-byte)

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(FILE_NAME);

byte[] result;
using (Stream stream = await sampleFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        result = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```